# How to insulate from the noise generated by rain falling on a roof window?

Tags: roof, sound-proofing, rain

My sleeping room is just below the roof, and has two roof windows. When it rains during the night (rather common experience during winter in central Italy, where I am located), the rain falling on the window glass generates a rather strong noise, which prevents me from getting asleep and often also wakes me up if I am already sleeping.

What are good sound-proofing techniques in this case? For example, would putting some layers of foam (which foam in particular?) just below the window work? Is the sound-proofing foam used in recoding studio the appropriate material here?

I've also thought about putting a layer of (not necessarily sound-proofing) foam *on* the window instead of below it, in the hope that the rain doesn't fall directly on the glass, so it makes less noise. It is clearly is a maintenance burden (the foam gets soaked, and it probably quickly breaks because of exposure to sun and wind), but maybe it works better. Are there suggestions about this idea?

Some remarks about my specific situation:

- The area is quiet, so the only noise I need to insulate from is the rain tapping on the roof window. Nothing else.
- I am renting the house, therefore I would like to minimise the modifications on the house. However, not being able to sleep is a serious problem and the landlord is a reasonable person, so if there is need I can try to negotiate some long-lasting change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is like most skylights (roof windows) there is a space below the window where you could stuff something to deaden the sound - acoustical insulation.

If you cut a piece of styrofoam insulation just slightly wider than the opening, you can press it in and it will stay on its own.  You can cover the exposed side with something so it looks OK.

You could cut a piece of plastic bubble wrap the size of the glass pane and attach it to the outside of the glass with silicone sealant.  This would not be too hard to remove, and would let most of the light through.   I doubt it will last long in the sunlight but maybe you'd only need a fresh piece once a year.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, but it is the rain on the roof...

Then there are the cows that moo with bells that clang that come down from higher pastures for the winter.

I learnt to sleep through “natural” noises, but perhaps that comes from growing up in the countryside.

Putting a shield over the window surface may help, but you might find the noise of rain hitting another surface then becomes more apparent.